# Specifying password in MySQL connection string

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, yeoman

I created ExpressJS MVC app using MySQL as DB with Yeoman generator
and in `config.js` I want to change MySQL connection strings, but I don't know to specify password in string.

my string is `mysql://root@localhost:3306/`

Please help me.

Comment: you need password as well as db name like: `mysql://root:password@localhost:port/dbName`

Comment: @UmairAhmed Thank you very much! if you will write answer I will make it accepted.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Password and DB name also a part of connection string. 
Ex: `mysql://root:password@localhost:port/dbName`

Comment: This is what I need!

Comment: If you have special characters like `#` in password you need to encode them as `%23`. You can use JS Method `encodeURIComponent` to find any characters encoded form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's generic [connection-string](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string) parser, which offers a flexible optional syntax, while adhering to the URL syntax. Works in any environment.

```js
const { ConnectionString } = require('connection-string');

const cs = new ConnectionString('mysql://user:password@host:port/dbName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'YOURPASSWORD',
  database : 'YOURDATABASE'
});
```

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/).

If this doesn't work, you should provide us with more information.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using knex. Setting up a connection pool that manages your pool for you is trivial. See the [documentation](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client).

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```