# Why is express-myconnection returning "undefined" connection parameter?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I've got a basic Node JS app (as I'm just learning). I'm using express, express-generator, express-myconnection, and mysql.

The issue has to do with querying the database connection itself.

The app is designed using an MVC structure.

Edit: to start off, here is my "app.js":

```
            var express = require('express');
            var path = require('path');
            var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
            var logger = require('morgan');
            var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
            var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

            var index = require('./routes/index');
            //var users = require('./routes/users');

            var app = express();

            var connection = require('express-myconnection');
            var mysql = require('mysql');

            app.use(

                connection(mysql,{

                    "host":"localhost",
                    "user":"root",
                    "password":"root",
                    "port":3306,
                    "database":"fruits"

                },'request')

            );

            // view engine setup
            app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
            app.set('view engine', 'pug');

            // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
            //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
            app.use(logger('dev'));
            app.use(bodyParser.json());
            app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
            app.use(cookieParser());
            app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

            app.use('/', index);

            // catch 404 and forward to error handler
            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
              var err = new Error('Not Found');
              err.status = 404;
              next(err);
            });

            // error handler
            app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
              // set locals, only providing error in development
              res.locals.message = err.message;
              res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

              // render the error page
              res.status(err.status || 500);
              res.render('error');
            });

            module.exports = app;
```

I have a model file, "fruits.js":

```
            var fruits = function(data, req){
                this.data = data;
                this.req = req;
            }

            fruits.prototype.data = {};

            fruits.prototype.getAll = function(callback){

                this.req.getConnection(function(err, connection){

                    console.log(connection);

                    //var q = connection.query("SELECT * FROM `fruits`", function(err, rows){

                        //callback(rows);

                    //});

                });


            };

            module.exports = fruits;
```

Then I also have a controller file (index.js):

```
            var express = require('express');
            var router = express.Router();

            var fruits = require('../models/fruits.js');

            /* GET home page. */
            router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
              res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
            });

            /*GET fruits page */
            router.get('/fruits',function(req, res, next){

                var f = new fruits({}, req);

                f.getAll(function(fruitsObj){

                    console.log(fruitsObj);

                    res.render('fruits',{
                        "title":"Fruits!",
                        "fruits":fruitsObj
                    });

                });
            });

            module.exports = router;
```

What happens is whenever the fruits route is navigated to, I can't query the database. It says that the "connection" from "this.req.getConnection" is "undefined".

Is there any reason why I can't retrieve the database connection and query it based on the contents of these two files? I'm positive I have all my packages installed. I even ran `npm install` for all them again to make sure.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It looks like a configuration issue. Which way you set up db connection parameters in your app? I mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105681/3211932

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Don't you have any configuration error on the App start? what exactly says the log? and are you sure that the password is "root"?

Comment: There's no errors on startup, surprisingly. And yes, the password is indeed "root". I've also tried setting the 'request' parameter for the connection to 'pool', which yields no change.

Comment: Well, try to move `app.use(connection(mysql, ...))` before routes requiring `require('./routes/index')`

Comment: Yup. Already have that in place. It's very strange, isn't it? I'm going to have my professor look at it tomorrow as well.

Comment: So, moving the connection middleware definition before the routes requiring doesn't work? ...it would be great if you post right answer here when you get it